# SD Card will mount on one machine and not on another

Tags: usb-drive, sd-card

I have two laptops with SD Card slots. One (machine 1, Ubuntu 18.04) has the SD Card mount as /dev/mmcblk0. The other (machine 2, Ubuntu 20.04) mounts SD Cards as block devices /dev/sdx where x is some integer.

Machine 1 will mount a micro SD Card without problem when in a brand name SanDisk adapter.
Files can be written and read to the card to it's full advertised capacity of 16GB.
dd can write zeros to this card to the full advertised capacity.
f3probe, f3write and f3read give the SD Card a clean bill of health

Machine 2 will not mount the same SD Card in the same adapter at all. lsblk shows no block device for it. udevadm monitor shows nothing happening when the SD Card is inserted into the reader. The Disks utility reports a 2.2TB drive when I insert the SD Card.

This SD Card is known to have some sort of problem as it can fool an SD Card duplicator into thinking it has a successful copy but no files are actually copied.

I am at a loss to explain this behavior or how to perform additional tests. Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: How old is the SD card reader in Machine 2? Does it recognise SDHC cards? Does it recognise SDXC cards? If it's an older device, it may be based on SD v1.0, which supported cards up to 4GB in size 